# Create superclass with abstract variables and nonabstract methods in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, interface, abstract

Basically, the superclass should contain variables (or properties, whichever one works) that will be set in the subclasses and should also contain methods that all the subclasses will use.  I don't know if there is a way to do this without using 2 classes, one that's an interface that contains the variables and another class that contains the methods, but I'd assume that there is.  I'm pretty new to C# as you might imagine.

Just to clarify, this is for a project in Unity and the superclass will be a general character class that all of the subclasses (characters) will use.

Edit: Many other variables and methods will be added later but here's a cursory preview of what it should be

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public abstract class CharacterClass : MonoBehaviour {

    int MaxHitPoints { get; set; }
    int ArmorRating { get; set; }
    int Speed { get; set; }
    int Strength { get; set; }
    int Agility { get; set; }

    void changeHP(int change)
    {
        MaxHitPoints += change;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the subclasses will set different default values or different constant values?

Comment: This is too general a question, could we see what you tried so far?

Comment: Set default values (i.e. changing max HP as a character levels)

Comment: Hi, sure you can trivially have "Inspector" variables in a component class, and then subclass that, and you'll see the Editor does what you're trying to do - there's a place you can change them all at once.  Just use trivial inheritance.

Comment: I have added a general look at what I need to do

Comment: Joe that just might work, many thanks.

Comment: note that in the example you edited in, you have a property "ArmorRating".  note tht you may be thinking of like "armor strength remaining" (so it runs from 11 down to 0 for strong beings, only 7 down to zero for lesser beings, and so on).  Your "armorRating" is just set by you ("the designer") at development time - right?  Hence, "11" for the first guy and "7" for the second guy, right?  Note that those would simply be **'Inspector'** variables in unity (ie, just mark them "public int ArmorStrength")

Comment: @Edogmonkey I believe what you are asking for is a superclass that defines the basic stuff, with child subclasses that override specific things (e.g. setting max HP).  Anything not overridden in the subclass will default to the superclass's definition.

Comment: right - I think he knows that as an experienced programmer, but the Unity case is bizarre/hard-to-get-used-to since all you're doing is making ***models*** of your (say) ten monster types. Those `GameObjects` sit around offscreen and you just instantiate them (perhaps in a pool, whatever) as needs be.  There is ***absolutely no 'Class' or anything like that*** which "is" Dino, Raptor, Croc.  Those things ***are just game objects, sitting around offscreen***.....

Comment: ........  There is ***only one*** GameObject in Unity, that's it.  The Cros might have "large teeth" and "short leg" components; raptor would have "fly" and "attack quickly".  Dragon might have "fireBreath" and so on.

Comment: recent chat on "new to Unity?!" topics heh ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37391504/294884

Comment: thus, @Edogmonkey, consider the "stuff" you mention HitPoints, Armor. Bashing, and so on .............. could well *just be* components.  Anything (at all) you want to add the concept of "armor strength" to ... you just drop on your "ArmorStrength" component.  ECS engines are entirely behavior based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the superclass will be a general character class

?  but wait, there's really no such thing - Unity is an ECS system.

All you can do is add components to `GameObject`s.  (That is to say, behaviors - all you can do is add behaviors (renderers, bone animators, timers, cameras, colliders, whatever) to `GameObject`s

There is no inheritance or anything like inheritance in Unity; it is not even vaguely OO.  Using Unity is much like using say Photoshop!

(Of course, the *language* that happens to be used currently as of writing, to write components in Unity is an OO language, but that's irrelevant, could change tomorrow. That doesn't make Unity in any way OO.)

Comment: Looks like I have a lot of reading up to do on this as I clearly have no idea what I'm doing.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented programming concepts are still usable in Unity to build entities from components.

```
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int HitPoints { get; set; }

    public virtual void ChangeHP(int amount)
    {
        HitPoints += amount;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("DeathTrigger"))
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Die()
    {
        Debug.Log("I'm dead.");
    }
}

public class LordOfTerror : Character
{
    protected override void Die()
    {
        base.Die();
        Debug.Log("But I also come back from the dead very soon.");
        HitPoints = 100;
    }
}
```

But it is true that this kind of programming only works for small inheritance trees and only with a few limitations or workarounds you would have to get used to in Unity. Generally, it makes sense to embrace components as much as possible. Here's a variation on the example showing how you could combine object-oriented with composition:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class StatAttribute
{
    public int current;
    public int min;
    public int max;

    public void Change(int amount)
    {
        current += amount;
    }
}

public sealed class Health : StatAttribute
{
    public event Action tookDamage;

    public bool isAlive
    {
        get { return current > min; }
    }

    public void Damage(int amount)
    {
        base.Change(-amount);
        // also fire an event to make other components play an animation etc.
        if(tookDamage != null)
            tookDamage();
    }
}

public sealed class Speed : StatAttribute
{
    public int boost;

    public int GetFinalSpeed()
    {
        return base.current * boost;
    }
}
```

Usually, you start with individual components attached to GameObjects. All combined make up your *Character*. You have things like *Health*, *CharacterMovement*, *PlayerInput*, *Animation*, etc. At some point your notice that code is duplicated and this is where it might make sense to share certain base classes between components.

Comment: *"Object oriented programming concepts are very well usable in Unity"*  Well the language used (presently) to write components is of course OO.  So, say as an engineer you are charged with writing three components (aka behaviors).  (Imagine, you don't even know what Unity is or what the use of your task is.) Of course as a skilled OO programmer, you would use OO principals (in c#) to *write those components*.  But as I mention in my answer, Unity is like using, say, Photoshop or a Spreadsheet....

Comment: Indeed, the second example here @xar shows exactly that ... OO is being used nicely to write components (aka behaviors).  Then in Unity (which is like .. Photoshop, or a spreadsheet), all you can do is paste them on.  (A very typical example ... say you have various projectiles; they can all **fly**.  So, some sort of coroutine to move them.  So you have various types of flight .. glide, fast attack, homing, parabola, zooming ... you know.)

Comment: I get what you're saying. At first it just sounded like you were saying that you cannot use any kind of inheritance in Unity projects. But I agree, the Unity side itself is a different approach overall than classic OO.

Comment: By all means, it's not unusual for folks to write code like your example "A".  BTW people invented the whacky term "ECS" (wikipedia is as good as anything) more or less to describe "Unity-like systems".  I think it's a poor term, but I do use it a bit (on this site for example).  Cheers!